# Which process sent data out of my computer?

Tags: networking, process, statistics

Using vnstat, I observed a lot of uploaded data from my computer and I don't know which process sent data out of my computer. Is there a tool to get stats on how much data a process consumed during a period of time? Thank you.

Update:
Looks like the process isn't sending data anymore, I installed `nethogs` to monitor live data transfer and everything seem totally normal.

Update:
Seems `nethogs` doesn't see the process which is sending data, the system monitor shows more data than `nethogs`. (see picture)

[image: System monitor shows the real data sending but can't tell which process is sending that data]

Update: 
After a long time of investigation, it poped in my mind that few months ago, I added in my crontab, a ping each 5 minutes to one of my website on Heroku to prevent the dyno to fall asleep. I remove this task and no more mysterious data sending. It is weird that `nethog` was not able to spot that.
Thank you for the help!

PS: It didn't work to ping the dyno on Heroku to prevent it to fall asleep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could install the package `nethogs` if it is available for your system. This command is similar to top and will show you your running processes and how much network traffic they are generating. Use this command sequence:

```
nethogs
nethogs my_interface(s)
```

If `nethogs` is not available you might try the `iptraf` command which will sort connections by usage. Then you can find the port and enter `lsof -i:the_suspect_port`

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/726601/15729. The version in jessie has the "creating socket failed while establishing local IP - are you root?", so I assume it is broken.

Comment: Note: 0.8.1 is easily backportable from unstable. I don't know why they haven't fixed/replaced the jessie version. –